# Playing videos on Phone gap application

Tags: android, video, cordova

I have been trying to play a video in an app which I am building with Phonegap for Android. I have tried video tag and that didn't work.

I tried video.js and jwplayer but even those were not working.

I tried to look for a solution, it loos like many people have faced the problem but I couldn't find a solution which worked for me.

Version 4.0 and above
[I have done the hardware acceleration thing and even that didn't work]

Comment: what you mean by not working ?? do u get sum error

Comment: Yes, the HTML 5 tag doesn't work. It shows some hardware issue..., then I tried with JW Player, it just says - error in video. And the Video.js said nothing :(